# Local host server package for Windows, Apache, SQL Server, and ASP or PHP?

Tags: sql-server, wamp

Does there exist a package like WAMP, but with SQL Server instead of MySQL? I'd be happy to work with either ASP or PHP, but PHP doesn't always play nice with SQL Server and ASP doesn't work with WAMP...so I'm doubtful on this.

I need this because I'm developing an IMS and it will eventually be hosted on an apache server, yet they require I use SQL Server (stupid...I know).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything like that.

But I suggest to install a Xampp instance:
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

And connect to a running instance of SQL Server using the MSSQL package (already integrated in Xampp) 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

```
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "your_name";
$myPass = "your_password";
$myDB = "examples";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT id, name, year ";
$query .= "FROM cars ";
$query .= "WHERE name='BMW'";

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);
```